# FCGI processes getting killed after a HTTP 502 error

Tags: c++, http, ubuntu, nginx, fastcgi

I have an FCGI application on an Nginx server and like all FCGI processes, this is persistent; as in it doesn't get killed after honoring a request and keeps waiting for the next request to be posted.

But, I noticed something strange today. Whenever I post a bad request and get a HTTP 502 error, the process is getting killed. Why is this, and how to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're reading it backwards. nginx issues a HTTP 502 when it cannot communicate with the fastcgi backend. It's likely *because* the fastcgi daemon died that you're getting HTTP 502, and not the other way around.

It's easy enough to check: just stick a breakpoint at the beginning of the call handler routine in your code, and submit enough requests to get the 502. Is the requested associated with the 502 hitting your breakpoint? Even if not, that doesn't mean this isn't the case. Your code could be crashing after replying to the previous request.